# Why chat.postEphemeral returns error for private channel?

Tags: slack-api

I am building a Slack App which show an ephemeral message to users if they send something to anywhere: direct messages, public channel or private channel. I added some events to my app according to [documentation](https://api.slack.com/events-api#subscriptions) and they actually work but posting an ephemeral message on these events works only for public channel and direct messages. For private channel and messages with myself I got "[channel_not_found](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral)" as error message. I got bot token type if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error message most likely is that your bot is not a member of the respective private channel.

A workaround is to ask the user to invite your bot user into every private channel he want to use your app.